# UICollectionView horizontal layout row breaking

Tags: ios, layout, uicollectionview

I am trying to achieve specific layout inside UICollectionView.

I need to adjust my phone layout to work well with iPad, so I used horizontal scrolling direction for "default" flow layout.

But unfortunately I am doing something wrong. Please look at following sketch:

[image: Sketch]

These are elements view:

- So far, I will not have too much cells, but maybe they will not fit (so I need to use UIScrollView derivate).
- One cell is double in size (plus one margin space), a very first one.
- Other cells are all same size (square)

As can be seen in sketch, row is not "breaking" in right moment (even after I played with contentSize) and 1st cell in 2nd row occupy two places.

If nothing helps, I will start with writing own UICollectionLayout descendant, but maybe it's something simple and can be done with "standard" flow layout.

Thank you.

[Sample file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75221195/HorizontalTestFlow.zip)

Comment: Could you add some code snippet for the same?

Comment: Hi, code is quite standard (DataSource from array, Delegate). But, now I have read that having cells "interlocked" (like Pinterest app have) is not possible with Flow layout at all, since flow layout require grid-like structure. Maybe I should start with writing my own UICollectionViewLayout descendant.

Comment: @Bojan can you post your code in order to help you, and see what is wrong? , regards

Comment: Hi, I will build now one simple demo project. Stay tuned, and thank you both.

Comment: I have attached very simple demo (only different colors of boxes). At moment demo have no need to scroll content, but as can be see layout issue is here. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to subclass UICollectionView.

I have followed tutorial from [Raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest), and converted vertical scrolling from their example to my horizontal layout.

I avoided using custom layout for long, but luckily it's not too bad at the end.